# How to sort rows by values in only one column in Matrix in SSRS

Tags: sorting, matrix, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a matrix in SSRS where the result looks like this:

```
            2.00%   3.00%   4.00%
Company A   1.2     1.35    1.45
Company B   1.1     1.26    1.41
Company C   1.8     2.1     3.12
Company D   2.3     2.5     3.92
```

I want to be able to sort the company names by the prices in only one of the columns.  For instance, if I choose to align by the 3.0% interest rate, the result would look like this:

Sorted by 3.0%:

```
            2.00%    3.00%  4.00%
Company D   2.3      2.5    3.92
Company C   1.8      2.1    3.12
Company A   1.2      1.35   1.45
Company B   1.1      1.26   1.41
```

How do I accomplish this with a matrix(cross table) in SSRS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you use a sort expression in the company group?

Something like:

=sum(iif(field!interestrate.value = "3.00%", field!price.value,0))

Comment: Thanks!  I finally got to test that and it works fantastically!